# Spark SQL - Encoders for Tuple Containing a List or Array as an Element

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 2.2 + Java 1.8

I have two custom data types "Foo" and "Bar". Each one implements serializable.'Foo' has a one to many relationship with 'Bar' so their relationship is represented as a Tuple:

```
Tuple2<Foo, List<Bar>>
```

Typically, when I have a 1:1 relationship, I can encode to my custom types like so:

```
Encoder<Tuple2<Foo,Bar>> fooBarEncoder = Encoders.tuple(Encoders.bean(Foo.class),Encoders.bean(Bar.class));
```

and then use to encode my Dataset

```
Dataset<Tuple2<Foo,Bar>> fooBarSet = getSomeData().as(fooBarEncoder);
```

But I am having trouble finding a way to encode for the scenario when I have a list (or an array) as a Tuple2 element. What I would like to be able to do is to provide an encoder for the second element like this:

```
Encoder<Tuple2<Foo,List<Bar>>> fooBarEncoder = Encoders.tuple(Encoders.bean(Foo.class), List<Bar>.class);
```

and then encode to my dataset:

```
Dataset<Tuple2<Foo,List<Bar>>> fooBarSet = getSomeData().as(fooBarEncoder)
```

But obviously I cannot invoke .class on a parameterized type like List

I know that for String and primitive types, arrays are supported by spark implicits e.g.:

```
sparkSession.implicits().newStringArrayEncoder()
```

But how would I create an encoder for a List or Array of a custom class type?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how well this method could be implemented within your setup but here goes. Create a wrapper class for your list and try it out.

```
public class BarList implements Serializable {
    List<Bar> list;

    public List<Bar> getList() {
        return list;
    }
    public void setList(List<Bar> l) {
        list = l;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know if it's possible. I tried the following Scala, trying to help, figuring that I could build up the encoder by first teaching spark how to encode X, then List[X] and finally a tuple containing List[X] (not shown below):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

class X(@BeanProperty var field: String) extends Serializable
case class Z(field: String)

implicit val XEncoder1 = Encoders.bean(classOf[X])

implicit val ZEncoder = Encoders.product[Z]

val listXEncoder = ExpressionEncoder[List[X]] // doesn't work
val listZEncoder = ExpressionEncoder[List[Z]]
```

listZEncoder works fine

Switching to use

```
implicit val XEncoder2 = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[X]
```

Still doesn't work for listXEncoder

The error ends up at a place in catalyst ScalaReflection, which is beyond me.